# multiplication of a periodic signal by rectangular pulse

Tags: signal

[image]

Here is the shape of rectangular pulse and sin(pi*t) in time domain
[image]

[image]

I am trying to sketch this signal, but I kind of don't fully understand the concept. 
since the two signal are multiplied in time domain, therefore the only area that survives is from -T/2 to T/2 ( bandwidth of rec) ?. Also it cannot be periodic, correct? and I am assuming it is energy type ( not power type) since the area of the signal is finite.  can anyone help me to sketch the x(t)? Thank you

Comment: You are correct, it is sinc(pi t) from -T to T (assuming that's how the PI function is defined in your class) and 0 everywhere else. Should be easy to sketch.

Comment: I think it will be from -T/2 to T/2 since the rec pulse is scaled

Comment: it is rectangular pulse

Comment: what about the survived area? what does it look like?

Comment: This is a homework question, and you didn't even try before you came and got help

Comment: @ Laptop it is a practice problem, and I have been discussing my answers since I posted this, I have doubts of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only area that survives is from -T/2 to T/2 (*width*, not *bandwidth* of the rectangle). Take the sinusoid , chop off everything below -T/2 and above T/2. Done. 

Update: Imagine a sine wave generator connected to a scope through a switch. Normally the switch connects the scope's input to ground (multiplication by zero), . At t=-T/2 it instanteneously connects it to the sine wave generator (multiplication by one). At t=T/2, back to ground. It's not an absolutely perfect analogy, mathematically, but I hope it helps.

Update 2: of course, the function is still defined and equals zero outside [-T/2, T/2].

Comment: can you sketch for me? what does it look like ?

Comment: what about from -T/2 to T/2 ?

Comment: I am just trying to figure out what it looks like , I drew it on paper but I don't know how to multiply them from -T/2 to T/2

Comment: x(t) = 0 outside [-T/2, T/2] (horizontal straight lines), inside it's sin(pi*t) (squiggly line) :)

Comment: no it is not sinusoid because it is multiplied by rectangular pulse, do you know what i mean?

Comment: It's a *segment* of a sinusoid, limited by -T/2 and T/2.

Comment: @user65652. what happens to something when you multiply it by 1?

Comment: @ Photon, interesting way of looking at it, does it really work that way? I thought I could bring the signal to frequency domain then do the convolution, that way it is easier to see it

Comment: A little learning is a dangerous thing...

Comment: Yes, \$x(t) = \sin(\pi{}t)\Pi(t/T)\$ means you multiply the value of the sine by the value of the rectangular pulse at each point in time.

Comment: @ photon, One more question please, is DC gain = 0 ? so I don't really have to evaluate the integral . since it is symmetric, you know what I mean?

Comment: Dc gain of a signal is just the average value of the signal, since it is symmetric, therefore the upper part cancels out the lower part of ( when doing the integration) = 0

Comment: No, you are describing the DC component of a signal.

Comment: Can we say x(t)= sin(pi*t) defined from -T/2 to T/2 ? just getting ride of rectangular pulse ? is that correct?

Comment: No, gain is not the same as offset. The function is defined from minus to plus infinity but equals zero outside the pulse (see the answer updated a few minutes ago). Try to get a solid understanding of basic concepts before getting into advanced topics. You would get the right answer by doing convolution in the frequency domain, as you were planning, but for this problem it's sort of like going from the kitchen to the living room by crawling out the window, walking on your hands around the house and getting back in through the living room window.

Comment: my bad, I meant DC component

Comment: now if I want to do the integration for x(t) ( to find evergy of the signal) , can i just get rid of rectangular pulse since it only  bonds the sin function, so I limit my sin function from -T/2 to T/2 and remove rectangular pulse, am I allowed to do that?

Comment: Yes, integrate the sine function from -T/2 to T/2.

Comment: But you won't find the energy of the signal by integrating x(t), by the way.